# Qt stylesheet to use an image from memory

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

Qt stylesheets allow customizing of icons, for example the drop-down icon in a combo box. But all examples and docs which I have yet seen require having the image stored in a url. Then you can write for example `QComboBox::down-arrow { image: url(path-to-file.png); }`.

My question is: isn't there any trick which would allow to work around the fact that the file must be stored somewhere and use for example a pixmap from the memory?

I am asking because recently I found a nice hack which allows using `QPixmap` data to be used when displaying images in widgets which otherwise accept richtext (HTML formatted). See this code:

```cpp
QPixmap preview;
// ... generate the pixmap here
QByteArray data;
QBuffer buffer(&data);
preview.save(&buffer, "PNG");
QString img = QStringLiteral("<img src='data:image/png;base64, %1'/>").arg(QString::fromLatin1(data.toBase64()));
//... and now you can display the image anywhere Qt accepts HTML formatted text, 
// e.g. in QToolTip (which is my usecase).
```

This way I can use data from memory without saving it to file.

I am curious if there isn't any similar trick for images used in Qt style sheets.

Comment: why you didn't add your image in `qrc` and then add its link from your resources?

Comment: Because I am generating the image by code. It is not a static image.

Comment: Is the image you generate changing quickly? Could saving it on the disk in a temporary folder (`std::filesystem::temp_directory_path`) and using the saved file in the stylesheet be a reasonable solution?

Comment: @Erel Of course it is a solution. But I just not feel this is right. Because why should I save something from memory to disk and then read it immediately from disk back to memory... I wush just looking for more straightforward in-memory-only solution.

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing special, just put path to your image:

```
setStyleSheet("background-image: url(/path/to/file.png);");
```

Comment: Of course, I know that I can use the path to a file... But this is exactly what I am trying to avoid. The reason is that I generate the image by code (i.e. I am painting it into pixmap). If stylesheet could somehow utilize the data from memory, then it would not be necessary to save it to some arbitrary file and then read it again when the stylesheet gets processed.

Comment: did you try QPalette?
`QPalette palette;
palette.setBrush(widget->backgroundRole(), QBrush(pixmap));
widget->setPalette(palette);`

Comment: Can this palette-approach be used in `QComboBox::down-arrow` stylesheet? How?